# Testing a method to return unique values from a result set of a db query

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, junit

Let's say there is a database table named "Students".

```
         Students Table
|---------------|---------------|
|     Name      |      Age      |
|---------------|---------------|
|     John      |       9       |
|---------------|---------------|
|     Jane      |       7       |
|---------------|---------------|
|     Dana      |       8       |
|---------------|---------------|
|     John      |       6       |
|---------------|---------------|
```

I make a request to the database to return all names using:

```
SELECT Name FROM Students
```

So the result set would be:

```
ResultSet rs = {"John" "Jane" "Dana" "John"}
```

I then want to return all unique values so I write a method called `populateSet()` to populate a `HashSet setOfNames` with `rs`.

After executing `populateSet(ResultSet rs)`, only unique names appear:

```
"John" "Jane" "Dana"
```

Here is the validation test:

```
public void testValidation() {
    // Skipping the test data / db connection / query part
    ResultSet rs = ResultSet received back from DB
    Set<String> expected = {"John", "Jane", "Dana"};
    Set<String> actual = WhateverClass.populateSet(rs);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

What are some of the possible unit tests that I could write?

I know I should write a null, empty, and negative tests. What are some corner cases?

Comment: You could also use the `SELECT DISTINCT` function in SQL.  This isn't an operation you want to do locally necessarily

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question. This was an interview question for a QE role.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential corner cases:

- Very large table (millions of rows)
- Transactionality - e.g, what happens if a name is inserted/deleted/updated after you start the table scan?
- Data ordering
- Case sensitivity/insensitivity of names
- non-ASCII characters in names

Comment: Good start.  I'd add null names if the column is nullable.